# EventHubError Sender Reconnect failed: Authorizacion timeout

Tags: python, authentication, error-handling, azure-eventhub

i have been sending events to eventhubs using the [python sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send), but i have been receiving this errors when sending data for some extended periods of around 1 hour and half sending data constantly, my goal is to send around 25 thousand events: 
[image]

My guess is that the uamqp connection requires to authenticate again after some time, and somehow the sdk is failing when trying to reconnect. How could i approach this failure? send smaller batches? close the connection after some sending and open it again? update to the [newer version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/get-started-python-send-v2) of the sdk? Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you always see auth failures after some fixed duration of time? Have you also run your clients with new SDK?

Comment: @SerkantKaraca I have not run my client with the new SDK, i am making the migration right now to test. I am making other tests right now and as of now i have been sending 80k of empty messages with no problem whatsoever, so i feel that the volume might be involded, i am running more tests today. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I will try to bring this to developer's attention.